# ArcGIS Raster Calculator Con() set 0 values to null

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, null, con

In some vides appear a process separated and I would like to do this two steps in one step:

1. set all values greater or equal to a number to 0:

   `Con("MyRaster" >= 2800, 0 , 1)`

the result is called "BandCloud.tif"

[image]

2. use created mask of 0 and 1 is to give 0 value to clouds and keep the rest of the data in "MyRater":

   `floar("MyRaster" * "BandClud")`

the results is a ratser where are cloud values are equal to 0 and the rest is the data "MyRaster"

So, finally I get a raster of my data ("MyRaster") and 0 for clouds

[image]

But would liker to directly in the same first conditional (1) to set could values not to 0 but directly to null, I did it in a third step:

3. set 0 values to null:

   `SetNull("MyRaster" == 0, "MyRater")`

[image]

How could this be done with raster calculator in ArcGIS?

Comment: Not sure I understand exactly what you want. If I misunderstand please clarify your question. You should be able to nest you raster calculator commands. If you wan't the zeros from the first command to be nulls instead:
`Con("MyRaster" >= 2800, SetNull("MyRaster" >= 2800, "MyRaster"), 1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to set pixels to null when "MyRaster" >= 2800 and set everything else to the values of "MyRaster" all in one step, use this expression:

```
Con("MyRaster" < 2800, "MyRaster")
```

or this expression:

```
SetNull("MyRaster" >= 2800, "MyRaster")
```